# Why does `Tags.findOne();` return a TypeError?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, sequelize.js, typeerror

The `/tag [tag name]` command is supposed to send the tag description or a message if the tag doesn't exist. Currently I have no items in the model. When I run the command with any arguments I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')`. Here is my code: 
**commands/tag.js**:

```js
const { Tags } = require('../models/tag.js');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('tag')
        .setDescription('Show a tag.')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('name')
                .setDescription('The name of the tag')
                .setRequired(true)
        ),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const name = interaction.options.getString('name');

        const tag = Tags.findOne({where: { name: name } });

        if (tag) return interaction.reply(tag.get('description'));

        return interaction.reply('That tag doesn\'t exist!');
    }
}
```

**models/tag.js**:

```js
module.exports = (db, DataTypes) => {
    return db.define('tags', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
        },
        description: DataTypes.TEXT,
    });
}
```

**db-init.js** (this is run manually):

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const db = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: './database.sqlite',
});

require('./models/tag.js')(db, DataTypes);

const force = process.argv.includes('--force') || process.argv.includes('-f');

db.sync({ force }).then(async () => {
    console.log('Database synced.');

    db.close();
}).catch(console.error);
```

**commands/addTag.js**:

```js
const { Tags } = require('../models/tag.js');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('addtag')
        .setDescription('Create a tag!')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('name')
                .setDescription('The name of your tag')
                .setRequired(true)    
        )
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('description')
                .setDescription('The tag description')
                .setRequired(true)
        ),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const name = interaction.options.getString('name');
        const description = interaction.options.getString('description');

        try {
            const tag = await Tags.create({
                name: name,
                description: description,
            });

            return interaction.reply(`Tag \`${tag.name}\` created.`);
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.name = 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError') return interaction.reply('That tag already exists!');

            return interaction.reply({ content: 'An error occured.', ephemeral: true });
        }
    }
}
```

The `/addtag [tag name] [tag description]` command is supposed to create a tag or send a message if the tag already exists. Whenever I run the command, I don't get any errors but the bot says the tag already exists even though it doesn't. Can someone please explain why these commands don't function properly?

Answer (score 0):

In your `commands/tag.js` you are requiring `const { Tags } = require('../models/tag.js');` which is just a function definition to define a database, not the actual database. That function doesn't have a definition of 'findOne' like javascript is responding.

you probably need to create the db object like you are in the `db-init.js` file