# Why do I get `Cannot read properties of undefined` while trying to import a Sequelize model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, typeerror

This is based on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74681008/why-does-tags-findone-return-a-typeerror) but more simple because I've figured out the issue is because I did something wrong with `module.exports`. I'm trying to figure out why I get a TypeError whenever I use any function of the model I created in another file. I have this test code: 
**index.js**:

```js
const { Test } = require('./model.js');

(async () => {
  const test = await Test.create({ name: 'test', desc: 'hello world' });

  console.log(test.name);
})();
```

**db-init.js** (run manually):

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const db = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: './database.sqlite',
});

require('./model.js')(db, DataTypes);

db.sync({ force: true }).then(async () => {
  console.log('db connected');
}).catch(console.error);
```

**model.js**:

```js
module.exports = (db, DataTypes) => {
  return db.define('test', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    desc: DataTypes.TEXT,
  });
}
```

The code should print "hello world", but instead I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')`. Sorry if this question is poorly worded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const { Test } = require('./model.js');
```

and

```js
require('./model.js')(db, DataTypes);
```

aren't used the same way. The correct one is the registration (function call).
In order to use the registered model you need to get it from Sequelize instance:

```js
// here you need to import `db` - Sequelize instance, like created in `db-init.js`
const db = require('./db.js);
const Test = db.models['Test'];
```

If you don't want to use `db-init.js` as a module with all registered models along with the Sequelize instance then you need a module that you can import whenever you need to use a registered model:

```js
// db.js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const db = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: './database.sqlite',
});

require('./model.js')(db, DataTypes);

module.exports = db
```

I'd recommend to look at my other answer to get an idea how to register models and their associations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618)